# Why my function secondMethod is not a function TypeError: (...).secondMethod is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, methods, chain

I am try to make a chainable instance for a personal project, and I try this simple example with some modifications, but I got a error:

```
TypeError: chainableInstance.firstMethod(...).secondMethod is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/rodger/Developer/Projects/Personal/unknown/src/teste.js:48:33)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

And my code is this:

```
  otherMethod(a) {
    return (this.a = a.replace('!e', 'e'));
  }
}
class Another extends Other {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  anotherMethod(a) {
    console.log('This is anohter method');
    return (this.a = a.replace('!d', 'd !e'));
  }

  otherMethod() {
    return super.otherMethod(this.a);
  }
}

class ChainAble extends Another {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  firstMethod() {
    return (this.a = 'a !b');
  }

  secondMethod() {
    return this.a.replace('!b', 'b !c');
  }

  thirdMethod() {
    return this.a.replace('!c', 'c !d');
  }
  anotherMethod() {
    return super.anotherMethod(this.a);
  }
}

const chainableInstance = new ChainAble();
chainableInstance.firstMethod().secondMethod().thirdMethod().anotherMethod();

console.log(chainableInstance);
```

I just not undestand why my secondMethod is It is considered "not a function", have someone to see what I am wrong in this stuff?

Comment: Calling some class `Chainable` doesn't make it chainable. You actually need to return an instance from the first method for that! None of your methods even returns an object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Method Chaining in a Javascript Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48219415/method-chaining-in-a-javascript-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is what you need

**Example**

```js
class Another {
  constructor() {
  }

  anotherMethod(a) {
    console.log('This is anohter method');
    this.a = a.replace('!d', 'd !e');
    return this;
  }

  otherMethod() {
    return super.otherMethod(this.a);
  }
}

class ChainAble extends Another {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  firstMethod() {
    this.a = 'a !b';
    return this;
  }

  secondMethod() {
    this.a = this.a.replace('!b', 'b !c');
    return this;
  }

  thirdMethod() {
    this.a = this.a.replace('!c', 'c !d');
    return this;
  }
  anotherMethod() {
    return super.anotherMethod(this.a);
  }
}

const chainableInstance = new ChainAble();
chainableInstance.firstMethod().secondMethod().thirdMethod().anotherMethod();

console.log(chainableInstance);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `firstMethod` returns the string `'a !b'` (the result of assignment). You need to return directly `this` from any methods that need to be chainable